# How Postgres determines the size of JSon column? (Or what Am I missing?)

Tags: json, postgresql, size

While studying ways to optimize the size of tables with JSon content, I came across an unexpected situation: a column with a supposedly smaller JSON takes up more space in the database.

Two tables were created in the test, both with a bigint and an array JSon column. The difference between the tables ("current" and "proposal") is the smaller number of items that make up the array in the second table. Which, supposedly, decreased its size, right?

[image: Comparing both tables]

Not exactly. For some reason, the "proposal" table takes more space, even having less itens composing its JSON. To make sure I'm not doing nothing really stupid, follow some additional info and instructions used to read and create ddata.

SQL to read the above image data:

```
SELECT current.a as json_current, 
       pg_column_size(current.a) as column_size_current,
       jsonb_array_length(current.a) as array_length_current,
       proposal.a as json_proposal, 
       pg_column_size(proposal.a) as column_size_proposal,
       jsonb_array_length(proposal.a) as array_length_proposal
  FROM current
 INNER join proposal on proposal.id = current.id
```

Both tables were created using:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name AS 
SELECT source.id,
       to_jsonb(
          (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(e)))
           FROM (SELECT source.idprop1,
                        COALESCE(source.idprop2, 0),
                        COALESCE(source.idprop3, 0),
                        source.prop4,
                        source.prop5
                 FROM source
                 WHERE source.id_master = master_source.id_master
                ) e 
          )
       ) as a
FROM master_source
GROUP BY master_source.id
```

With the second table (proposal) having following additional clauses to its WHERE:

```
AND (source.prop2 is not null 
     OR source.prop3 is not null 
     OR (source.prop4 is not null and source.prop3 > 0)
     OR (source.prop5 is not null and source.prop4 > 0)
```

Is there anything am I missing or expected from Postgres to achieve this result?

**UPDATE: ABOUT TOAST**

As expected, tables to store large text were created but, as we can see in the following image, JSON values are not large enought to be stored there.

[image: TOAST information]

Comment: Perhaps the values in the first table were big enough to get stored out of line in a TOAST table. Compare `pg_total_relation_size`.

Comment: @Laurenz, I will do that as soon as I can, ty!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I did some research and find out that the TOAST is not even being used (the toast table is empty) since JSON have not reached the default size (8kb). 

While reading about how large valus and TOAST works, tough, I saw something that may explain: compression. Maybe - I really can't say - the second table with more unique values produces not the best compressed result that the first table. As I said, a guess.

Not sure what to do with the question. Should I close it?

Comment: With the amount of information we have at this point, yes, you should close it. If you provide more data points (e.g., the actual values, the binary data in the columns as displayed with `pageinspect`, ...), the question could receive an answer.